# What happens to IBinder on onServiceDisconnected()?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

Say I've created a bound service, and it has successfully bound and called onServiceConnected(). Now I have an IBinder object that I want to make a remote call with.

But, if between getting the IBinder and the remote call, the service is suddenly disconnected, what happens to the IBinder? Does it become null? Does it throw an exception if I try to use it?

Also, if a service does a lot of connecting/disconnecting, is the IBinder object the same instance on every connect, or is it different?

Answer (score 0):

`onServiceDisconnected` is called when the remote process has crashed and the connection is no longer established. Because of this, you shouldn't attempt to use the `IBinder` after this occurs.